# SSRS 2008 config for SharePoint 2010 integration - Permissions question

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have SharePoint 2010 and SQL server 2008 setup on two machines. I have SharePoint using SQL server for all SP databases.  I am trying to get reporting services integration to work, but there seems to be some permissions issue with the SSRS service.  From what I understand, it should be possible to navigate to http://server-name/ReportServer and get a simple page showing the server path and the SQL Server version number.  This page is only available to windows users with accounts on the local machine.

Both of my machines are on the same domain with "domain level" service accounts.  This used to be covered under IIS, but SSRS 2008 no longer uses IIS -- so im unsure how to research it.  Ive tried folder permissions for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services" with no luck - Im not sure which .config file is the right one either.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page is nice:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522743.aspx

Have you gone through the SSRS config tool?  You should step through each tab and make sure it is configured.

Errors can be found in the instance directory as well.

What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes, I used the configuration tool - completely. No errors, just no access to the reporting server URL by any domain account (even domain administrators). Only local users have permission.

Comment: By no access, do you mean a blank page?